# Is there any way to represent an OsStr or OsString literal?

Tags: rust

I'd like to define an `OsStr` constant for an extension comparison that's going to happen many times. For example:

```
const DCM_EXTENSION: Option<&'static OsStr> = Some("dcm");
const DCM_EXTENSION: Option<&'static OsStr> = Some(OsStr::new("dcm"));
```

This should make it trivial and unfallable to do the comparison:

```
if entry.file_type().is_file() && entry.path().extension() == DCM_EXTENSION:
```

Neither method works due to lack of const fn and a type mismatch, respectively.

My current workaround is to convert at runtime before doing any comparisons:

```
const DCM_EXTENSION_STR: Option<&'static str> = Some("dcm");

main!(|args: Cli, log_level: verbosity| {
    let dcm_extension = DCM_EXTENSION_STR.map(OsStr::new);
    // ...
});
```

I figure this avoids a per-access penalty that lazy_static would impose and works out to a one-time runtime penalty that is negligible.

Comment: See also [How to match a file extension represented as an OsStr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42101070/155423).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is not (yet).

However, `OsStr::new` cannot fail (it does not return a `Result` or list any panic conditions). `AsRef` is "a cheap reference-to-reference conversion".

This means you can create a string literal and convert it to an `OsStr` at the site of use and expect there to be basically no overhead. Inspecting the assembly may even show that the types completely disappear at compile time (zero overhead).