# How to to pattern match an Option<&Path>?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

My code looks something like this:

```rust
// my_path is of type "PathBuf"
match my_path.parent() {
    Some(Path::new(".")) => {
        // Do something.
    },
    _ => {
        // Do something else.
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
expected tuple struct or tuple variant, found associated function `Path::new`
for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-00-patterns.html
```

I read [chapter 18 from the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-00-patterns.html) but I couldn't figure out how to fix my specific scenario with the `Path` and `PathBuf` types.

How can I pattern match an `Option<&Path>` (according to the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.parent) this is what the `parent` methods returns) by checking for specific values like `Path::new("1")`?

Comment: [How to match a file extension represented as an OsStr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42101070/155423)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a `match`, then you can use a [match guard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/guard.html). In short, the reason you can't use `Some(Path::new("."))` is because `Path::new(".")` is not a [pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html).

```rust
match my_path.parent() {
    Some(p) if p == Path::new(".") => {
        // Do something.
    }
    _ => {
        // Do something else.
    }
}
```

However, in that particular case you could also just use an if expression like this:

```rust
if my_path.parent() == Some(Path::new(".")) {
    // Do something.
} else {
    // Do something else.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Two options, convert the `path` into a `str` or use a match guard. Both examples below:

```rust
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn map_to_str(my_path: PathBuf) {
    match my_path.parent().map(|p| p.to_str().unwrap()) {
        Some(".") => {
            // Do something
        },
        _ => {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
}

fn match_guard(my_path: PathBuf) {
    match my_path.parent() {
        Some(path) if path == Path::new(".") => {
            // Do something
        },
        _ => {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=78f7d27d83cd67f954e4e78be97dc1d3)